# Filter taxonomy terms using multiple id in the edit-tags.php

Tags: taxonomy, search, terms

I want to use the edit-tags.php search function with multiple term id's. For example, if i type into the searchbox something like this: #1245&6832, it should display these two terms in the results table(WP_Terms_List_Table).

I tried to use the pre_get_posts action to get access to the query that is running for the search, but this is just showing me an "empty" query:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_terms_by_ids' );

function filter_terms_by_ids( $wp_query ) {
    global $pagenow;

    if($pagenow == 'edit-tags.php' && $_GET['s']):
        print_r($wp_query->query_vars);
    endif;

}
```

My idea is to check the $_GET['s'] and if # is the first character, i can modify the query to only include these terms in the search:

```
if ('#' == substr($_GET['s'],0,1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to implement. All you need is your own hook for `get_terms_args` filter:

```
add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'wpse8170_get_terms_args', 10, 2  );
function wpse8170_get_terms_args( $args, $taxonomies ) {
    if ( !in_array( 'post_tag', $taxonomies ) ) {
        return $args;
    }

    $matches = array();
    if ( empty( $args['search'] ) || !preg_match( '/^\#(.*)$/', $args['search'], $matches ) ) {
        return $args;
    }

    if ( count( $matches ) == 2 ) {
        $args['search'] = '';
        $args['include'] = array_filter( array_map( 'intval', explode( '&', $matches[1] ) ) );
    }

    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works as excepted, i just needed to change post_tag to my taxonomy name.

Comment: @passatgt u r welcome